# Haskell: Memoising using MonadState inside a FreeMonad Interpreter

Tags: haskell, memoization, monad-transformers, state-monad, free-monad

Given that I have the following DSL (using a Free Monad) and its interpreter:

```
data MyDslF next =
    GetThingById Int (Thing -> next)
  | Log Text next

type MyDslT = FT MyDslF

runMyDsl :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => MyDslT m a -> m a
runMyDsl = iterT run
  where
    run :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => MyDslF (m a) -> m a
    run (Log message continue)      = Logger.log message >> continue
    run (GetThingById id' continue) = SomeApi.getThingById id' >>= continue
```

I would like to change the interpreter internally to use MonadState so that if a `Thing` has already been retrieved for a given `Id`, then there is no second call to `SomeApi`

Lets assume I already know how to write the memoised version using `get` and `put`, but the problem I am having is running the `MonadState` inside `runMyDsl`.
I was thinking the solution would look similar to:

```
type ThingMap = Map Int Thing

runMyDsl :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => MyDslT m a -> m a
runMyDsl = flip evalStateT mempty . iterT run
  where
    run :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m, MonadState ThingMap m) => MyDslF (m a) -> m a
    run ..
```

But the types do not align, since `run` returns `(.. , MonadState ThingMap m) => m a` and `evalStateT` expects `StateT ThingMap m a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `iterTM` instead of `iterT`:

```
runMyDsl :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => MyDslT m a -> m a
runMyDsl dsl = evalStateT (iterTM run dsl) Map.empty
  where
  run (Log message continue)      = logger message >> continue
  run (GetThingById id' continue) = do
    m <- get 
    case Map.lookup id' m of
      Nothing -> do 
         thing <- getThingById id' 
         put (Map.insert id' thing m)
         continue thing
      Just thing -> continue thing
```

Equivalently, you can use `iterT` if you first raise `MyDsl m a` to an `MyDsl (StateT Int m) a` using `hoistFT lift`, like so:

```
runMyDsl :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => MyDslT m a -> m a
runMyDsl dsl = evalStateT (iterT run (hoistFT lift dsl)) Map.empty
```

This makes `dsl` into a `MyDsl (StateT Int m) a` that doesn't actually involve any state updates, though `run` does involve state transitions.